Did the last eukaryotic common ancestor (LECA) have meiosis?
I know that sexual reproduction - meisosis - predates multicellular organisms, but did it evolve only once, in LECA, or did it evolve once in a subgroup of eukaryotes, or did it evolve multiple times?
Did meiosis evolve only once? Is it ancestral to all eukaryotes (i.e. coming from LECA)?

This is a great question and the subject of a number of scientific articles, e.g. this review from 2015. Here is their one-line summary quoted:

In summary, long-term asexuality is rare, and there is growing consensus that meiotic sex was present in the LECA and remains so in all major eukaryotic lineages

Here's my longer summary.
Historically, answering this involved catching organisms 'in the act', phenotypically: observing meiotic, a.k.a., 'reductional' cell divisions (diploid -> haploid cells), or fusions of gametes, or fusions of nuclei, both also necessary components of eukaryotic sex.
A more comprehensive approach is to survey eukaryotic species genomically: by looking for genes involved in meiosis, cell fusion, or nuclear fusion, in the genomes of all known eukaryotes, or at least a set of species representative of the full diversity of eukaryotes. The answer so far is that all major eukaryotic clades have representatives with genes encoding these features, supporting the idea that sex is an ancestral feature and was probably present in LECA.
Note that some lineages of eukaryotes are entirely asexual, including some multicellular organisms - notably bdelloid rotifers . In addition many single-celled eukaryotes are facultatively sexual, i.e. can reproduce asexually for many generations, e.g. ciliates and many other protists. Either way, loss of sex (and the associated sex-essential genes) is likely a secondary event: looking at a tree of eukaryotes with presence/absence of sex, it is much simpler to assume that it was gained early, and subsequently lost in a few lineages, than initially absent, and subsequently gained in many lineages. This is called 'parsimony' in evolutionary/tree-based thinking.
Finally, note that only a survey of all extant (=currently living) eukaryotic lineages, including potentially lineages that have as of yet never been observed, can definitively answer this question: if we find a single lineage of eukaryotes that is highly-diverged from all other known eukaryotes (=has been around in this form since LECA), and shows no evidence of sex, maybe sex evolved after LECA. Indeed, while it looks like sex evolved concurrently with the first eukaryotic cell, exactly why remains unclear: why would the emergence of a eukaryotic cell (= having a nucleus and having membrane-bound organelles like mitochondria) and of sex co-occur?
